# @font-face uncaught syntax error in chrome

Tags: html, css, font-face

Gone through some other threads regarding a similar problem, but their solution didn't work. I had been successfully using the code below to add a font to our site which was based off a comprehensive bootstrap template. I now started work on a new site, this time from only a base bootstrap template and tried to add fonts via the same method.

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: 'myfontname';
   src: url('font/myfontname-Regular.svg'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Regular.eot'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Regular.woff') format('woff'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype') 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'myfontname';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('font/myfontname-Bold.svg'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Bold.eot'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
   url('font/myfontname-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype') 
}

.myfontnameBOLD{
  font-family: myfontname; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.myfontnameREG{
  font-family: myfontname; 
}
```

Files are all stored in the same manner as previous ( a Font folder within my css folder). However this time I get the following error

> uncaught syntaxError:Invalid or unexpected token

In Chrome the debug highlights the very first line where it says  "@font-face"
I ran this through a Linter and no problem, but even I.E is giving an error and highlighting @font-face and saying it has a missing semi-colon.
 Anyone able to see what might be wrong? thanks

Comment: What is the css before this - there may be an error in the code before causing this line to be picked up as the error (eg not closing a bracket or something similar)

Comment: no css before it, this is the only css it contains. thanks

Comment: what about other stylesheets included before?

Comment: are you using a reaaally old browser?

Comment: no, chrome is latest and its IE 9.

Answer (score 22):

ok I found the answer and it was a silly one. thanks for your replies. the problem was the actually declaration of the css file in my HTML. I had put it in `<script>` tags by mistake instead of `<link>`. *slaps self*

Comment: :D - Did exactly the same. Thanks for the hint - thats something you wont see if you look on it again and again and again...

Comment: Exactly the same. jaja. Thanks!!

Comment: A year later, did exactly the same from me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the missing semi-colon after `url('font/myfontname-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype')` and `url('font/myfontname-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype')` ?

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'myfontname';
   src: url('font/myfontname-Regular.svg'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Regular.eot'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Regular.woff') format('woff'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'myfontname';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('font/myfontname-Bold.svg'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Bold.eot'); 
   src: url('font/myfontname-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), 
   url('font/myfontname-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
   url('font/myfontname-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'); 
}
```

I've added the semi-colon

Comment: thank you. unfortunately no luck. it is a strange one. as I say same code copy and pasted works for same browser on another site.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **Ayush's** answer may solve your problem! I would also like to add that the order in which the fonts are loaded may create some problems in some browsers and platforms. The order in which the src element is read varies depending on what browser and version are using it. Take the example below from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/),

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compatible Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

It's best to include SVG last because it might be picked up by some browsers (like the modern ones) where woff or woff2 is supported.

Comment: thanks, I did this due to a problem with Chrome not loading the font on the previous site I used this. A stackoverflow entry suggested moving svg to the top and it seemed to fix it. But I tried the suggestion here and no luck with this particular problem.